# Heavily nested bin cond operator takes too much time while preparing the execution plan PIG 0.11

Tags: apache-pig

I need to generate last day of the month using the month provided. Each row in file contains Month in int form. Below if the code I want to execute on PIG. It was working fine on PIG 0.8 (CDH 3) but when I tries to executes the same on PIG 0.11 (CDH 4) it takes too much time (approx 4 mins on my cluster having 6 nodes).

```
    A = LOAD '/user/recengd/hitesp/pig/prb' USING PigStorage(',') AS (month:int);
    B = FOREACH A GENERATE  (month== 1 ? 31:
     (month== 2 ? 28:
     (month== 3 ? 31:
     (month== 4 ? 30:
     (month== 5 ? 31:
     (month== 6 ? 30:
     (month== 7 ? 31:
     (month== 8 ? 31:
     (month== 9 ? 30:
     (month== 10 ? 31:
     (month== 11 ? 30:31))))))))))) ;

     Data
     1
     2
     9
     7
```

When I execute the second line having conditions for 9 months (i.e. 9 inner cond) it works fine. But once nested conditions goes beyond that number it starts to slow down the process. I tried it on grunt as well and having same problem. I am not sure if it is some setting issues or there is really a issue with latest release.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CASE expression!  It is new in pig 0.12:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (
    CASE month
        WHEN 1 then 31
        WHEN 2 then 30
        ...
    END 
);
```

references:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3268
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution:

generate a text file with two columns:

```
1,31
2,28
3,31
4,30
5,31
6,30
7,31
8,31
9,30
10,31
11,30
12,31
```

load the file as so:

```
month_day = load '/month_day.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (month:int, day:int);
```

Then join the alias to A:

```
C = join A by (month), month_day by (month);
```

And voila! you have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had trouble using nested binconds before, but I guess it's possible I've never gone above 9 conditions.  That said, if it works fine with smaller numbers of conditions, there's an easy way in this case to deal with it:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    (month == 2 ? 28 :
    (month == 4 OR month == 6 OR month == 9 OR month == 11 ? 30 : 31));
```

Note that your approach does not handle leap years.

If you want a more compact way of expressing the second condition so you don't have to type all those `OR`s, you can do this to slightly shorten it:

```
((month-4)*(month-6)*(month-9)*(month-11) == 0 ? 30 : 31));
```

or use this hack to *really* shorten it:

```
A = LOAD '/user/recengd/hitesp/pig/prb' USING PigStorage(',') AS (month:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    (month == '2' ? 28 :
    (month MATCHES '(4|6|9|11)' ? 30 : 31));
```

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer. Thanks. However it still solves my problem partially. I have other conditions where I am mapping value to code. Each value maps to single code. Here I am again having nested binary condition. `(value='xyz'?1:(value='pqr'?2:(......)));` Want to know if its an issue with PIG 0.11 or my setup. Article (http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigTypesDesign) also suggests some changes have happened which could cause this issue.

Comment: At some point, if you have that many different codes to map to, you should just load that data as another alias and then `JOIN` it. Using a replicated join, it won't hinder performance and it will be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Would have done the same if possible through join. Actually it is mapping of a code which depends on combination of multiple columns. Condition looks like `(code1=val1?(cod2=val1?1:(code2=val2?2:(...))):(code1=val2?....))`. Condition is more complex here and for some combinations there is third parameter as well. I have two options here, keep the same code or write UDF. The same code is taking too much time to compile. Trying to find out if its a setup problem or some real issue with PIG 0.11 so that I can decide on using UDF instead.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but it sounds like you would be much better off writing a UDF will well-formatted if/then blocks rather than highly unreadable nested binconds.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs, WinnieNicklaus.

Comment: Code is hitting bug PIG 2769 a simple logic causes long delays